# How can I store a list of parse objects from one column into a HashSet?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, hashset, android-parsequeryadapter

If I have a String column "A" in a parse class. And I have 5 objects in column "A" with values:

```
1- A'
2- B'
3- C'
4- D'
5- E'
```

How can I retrieve those objects, and store them in  HashSet to be used?
So, if I `system.out.println` the HashSet values, it would show me A',B',C',D',E'.
**Note:** I am trying to add a list of parse objects into a hashSet. So I retrieve a whole column, like I said above, and store it into a hashSet.

Need more information? Ask instead of `-1`ing please.

Comment: you can not store HashSet in ParseObject, but you can store List object, there is Array inside that.

Comment: @AmitPrajapatic no, I want to store parseobjects in a hashset.